# does the old facebook sdk stopped working

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

i was using the old methods of facebook sdk(without fragments) in my app and they were working fine but from some time they are not behaving as expected.Well i can log in using facebook but it doesn't fetch data anymore,not even user name.it opens the web view for logging in but still can't fetch anything.also i want to invite my fb friends to use the app  but the new procedure is lengthy and complicated than the older one.So is it possible to use old methods instead of new one's.
here's the code i am using for logging in and fetching user name-

```
public class Profile_Fragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{
    ImageView login_facebook;

    String facebook_user_name;
    TextView fb_user_name,record_motivational_message;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_layout, null,false);
        init(view);
        setListener();
        setData();
        return view;




    }
    void init(View view){
        login_facebook=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.login_facebook);
        fb_user_name=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.fb_user_name);
        record_motivational_message=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView14);
    }
    void setListener(){
        login_facebook.setOnClickListener(this);
        record_motivational_message.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    void setData(){
        fb_user_name.setText(facebook_user_name);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.login_facebook:
            facebookConnect();
            break;
        case R.id.textView14:
            Dialog_Fragment alert=new Dialog_Fragment();
            alert.show(getFragmentManager(), "Your Message");
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    void facebookConnect(){
        Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

              // callback when session changes state
              @Override
              public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {

                  // make request to the /me API
                  Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        Log.v("facebook_user_name", "facebook_user_name");
                      if (user != null) {
                          Log.v("facebook_user_name", facebook_user_name);
                      facebook_user_name= user.getName();
                      Log.v("facebook_user_name", facebook_user_name);
                      }
                    }
                  }).executeAsync();
                }
              }
            });
          }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you share or login via facebook native app then you have to provide your app for review on Facebook Developer account.

Comment: thanks a lot,i read the whole doc and came to know that it needs to get reviewed.So i guess all old methods have stopped working and its getting more complex now :)

Comment: Have you think is my ans is match to your problem ?

Comment: yes that's what exactly i need to do

Comment: So shall i put my comment as ans and have you approve it ?

Comment: well i've already approved an answer that also suggest's the same.Sorry bro

Comment: I just ask for favor becz if some one have same problem then his/her have to first read doc then know why this happens that y ask to accept my ans.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58471/discussion-between-anirudh-sharma-and-haresh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below mentioned link provide you changes & available features while moving facebook v1.0 to v2.0.

Reference link :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Read it very carefully. They have given all the points in it.